# CPAN Install DBD::MariaDB failed on OS X 14

Tags: perl, mariadb, dbi, cpan

I am using a MacBook 14.1.1 Sonoma M2 chip and want my Perl scripts to talk to my MariaDB database. Installing DBI was no problem. However when trying to install DBD::MariaDB I get the following error:

"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- MariaDB.bs blib/arch/auto/DBD/MariaDB/MariaDB.bs 644 make: *** No rule to make target `/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI/Driver_xst.h', needed by` MariaDB.xsi'. Stop. PALI/DBD-MariaDB-1.23.tar.gz /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK Failed during this command: PALI/DBD-MariaDB-1.23.tar.gz : make NO

Does anyone know what the problem is here? The same error is happening when I was trying to download DBD:Pg

Comment: show exactly what you did to install DBI and what you did to try to install DBD::MariaDB

Answer (score 3):

The Perl installed with MacOS is not a complete development environment. It is missing things such as header files necessary to compile other modules. You can get these as part of the [XCode Command Line Tools](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/install-xcode-command-line-tools/), but there's some additional configuration necessary to actually use them.

It's better to **leave the system Perl alone**. Consider it part of the operating system. Any modules you install or upgrade may break parts of the OS, or be overwritten on the next OS update.

Instead, install your own Perl for development. You can do this with a package manager such as [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), generally very handy, or if you want more control use Perl's own [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/).

Comment: Thanks!  Perlbrew worked. I used cpanm to download the packages and its up and running with my MariaDB. As for DBD::Pg this is still not working however its giving me a different error:        Configuring DBD-Pg-3.17.0
Running Makefile.PL
Configuring DBD::Pg 3.17.0
DBI.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got first handshake key 0xc700080, needed 0x10200080)                                                                                      Any chance someone knows the fix?

Comment: @mhotchjr I'd suggest you ask another question. Your Perl installations might have somehow gotten cross wired.